# JPA Custom query to HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

How can I get the result of custom query into an `HashMap<String, Object>` without having no `Entity` model?

The idea is:
get data from this kind of table

```
+---------+---------+
| field_1 | field_2 |
+---------+---------+
| Hello     15      |
+-------------------+
| Bye       189     |
+-------------------+
```

have equivalent of this `Map` per row

```java
new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
    put("field_1", "Hello");
    put("field_2", 15);
}}
```

Example:

```java
// SELECT * FROM sample_table;
public List<Map<String, Object>> getSomeData()

// SELECT * FROM other_table;
public List<Map<String, Object>> getOtherData()
```

Comment: You can't, jpa is built [on entities](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-jpa-architecture). I don't know, how this idea comes up, jpa is not as general as C# linq, it's just a DB access layer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answer!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-dynamicmodels.html

Comment: It cannot be done in JPA query without entity. You can achieve this in native Quey.